# Validity check in java

Tags: java

If I want to check if a given by the user integer is positive,and if it's not return a message to the console asking to re-enter the number, how am I to implement it? I'm thinking something along the lines of the code below but can't continue my train of thought. Don't know what to type in the else statement. Any help is appreciated.

```
   int nJudges = readInt("Enter number: ");
        while(nJudges <= 0){
            nJudges = readInt("Enter number: ");
        }
```

Ok ok you were right. Thank you very much. This is solved.

Comment: Wrap this whole thing in a `do...while` loop. Save some information in the `else` to see whether to keep going.

Comment: you don;t even need else block, it is not mandatory

Comment: I agree with chylis, however to answer your question, in your else block write the message then readInt into num again

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
int num = readInt("Enter number: ");
while(num <= 0)
    num = readInt("Please enter a number greater than zero: ");
```

or

```
int num;
do {
    num = readInt("Please enter a number greater than zero: ");
} while (num <= 0);
```

Comment: While mostly the same as JoeC's below, I think this is the better implementation from a usability standpoint because it gives the user an idea about the validation criteria.

Answer (score 2):

The idea should be somewhat like this

```
int num = readInt("Enter number: ");
while(num <= 0){
    num = readInt("Enter number: ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
// a place to store user's selection
int selection = -1;
// this bit creates a while loop that assigns the input to `selection` using
// your `readInt` function. It's condition is that the result is greater than 0
while ((selection = readInt("Enter a number:")) < 0){
    // prompt user to select a valid number
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid number!");
}
// `selection` now stores the user's selection
enter code here
```

now you have the user selection in `selection`

**Understanding the while loop ([using chain assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chained_assignment#Chained_assignment))**:

In Java, [assignment is right associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Right-associativity_of_assignment_operators). This means that expressions like `a=(b=c)` should assign `c` to both `a` and `b`. To do this, the assignment operator `=` returns the value of the right operand. Therefore, the expression `a=b` returns `b`, and the expression we've used in the while loop:

```
(selection = readInt("Enter a number:"))
```

returns the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 0;
do
{
    num = readInt("Enter number: ");
    if (num <= 0)
        System.out.println("number is not positive");
}while (num <= 0);
```